# How can I send ERC20 tokens without a gas?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, erc20

How can I send ERC20 tokens without a gas?
Many different people says that it's imposible, but sender address has no eth for paying gas:

[BTB Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTJmZ.png)

[OMG Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpJKy.png)

How it works?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include *links* to the transactions as screenshots are more or less useless without full information.

Comment: Hello https://etherscan.io/tx/0x65054d94240f32ade5ecbde2ce98fc8377c4859feeb462bbb4b48e14dbcb30e6 https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa8df8825415c1e4a399ba4f21adb1c98517badec5246960f0b9aff93bd23347d

Comment: As  addresses in the comments below, it is likely an Etherscan bug.

Comment: Another explanation is that the transaction was mined privately and not through a public mempool. I.e. the sender was running their own Ethereum mining node.

Comment: Sender addres has no ETH on ballances but has ERC20 tokens. Somebody send ERC20 tokens without ETH on ballance of sender address.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not a user transaction, but some kind of token mining mechanism

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2ea5d72e92650013f0fda93bb1dd7cb365e990e6754c9bd9eb216005f58ffa7a#eventlog
- https://etherscan.io/address/0x4f38f4229924bfa28d58eeda496cc85e8016bccc#code - see MineableToken contract

Comment: My picture shows the FULL details of your transaction, which are CROPPED in your picture.
The transaction was not free.

Comment: But sender address has no eth for paying a gas. Who did it? Thanks.

Comment: I can send much more samples with other tokens. All was send from addresses without eth for gas to other address.

Comment: It says gas used by transaction 70,824, so it is likely just a bug to convert this to dollar value in Etherscan.